# failed on start-all.sh in Apache Hadoop single node setup

Tags: hadoop

I installed Apache Hadoop 1.0.4 on Ubuntu 12.04. I followed the instruction on http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/single_node_setup.html, and reached the section of "Execution". There I failed on $ bin/start-all.sh, and the error messages are as below. My username is anson.

```
$ start-all.sh
mkdir: cannot create directory `/var/log/hadoop/anson': Permission denied
chown: cannot access `/var/log/hadoop/anson': No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory `/var/run/hadoop': Permission denied
starting namenode, logging to /var/log/hadoop/anson/hadoop-anson-namenode-anson-Ubuntu-T430.out
/usr/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 136: /var/run/hadoop/hadoop-anson-namenode.pid: No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 135: /var/log/hadoop/anson/hadoop-anson-namenode-anson-Ubuntu-T430.out: No such file or directory
head: cannot open `/var/log/hadoop/anson/hadoop-anson-namenode-anson-Ubuntu-T430.out' for reading: No such file or directory
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory `/var/log/hadoop/anson': Permission denied
localhost: chown: cannot access `/var/log/hadoop/anson': No such file or directory
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory `/var/run/hadoop': Permission denied
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /var/log/hadoop/anson/hadoop-anson-datanode-anson-Ubuntu-T430.out
localhost: /usr/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 136: /var/run/hadoop/hadoop-anson-datanode.pid: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 135: /var/log/hadoop/anson/hadoop-anson-datanode-anson-Ubuntu-T430.out: No such file or directory
localhost: head: cannot open `/var/log/hadoop/anson/hadoop-anson-datanode-anson-Ubuntu-T430.out' for reading: No such file or directory
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory `/var/log/hadoop/anson': Permission denied
localhost: chown: cannot access `/var/log/hadoop/anson': No such file or directory
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory `/var/run/hadoop': Permission denied
localhost: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /var/log/hadoop/anson/hadoop-anson-secondarynamenode-anson-Ubuntu-T430.out
localhost: /usr/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 136: /var/run/hadoop/hadoop-anson-secondarynamenode.pid: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 135: /var/log/hadoop/anson/hadoop-anson-secondarynamenode-anson-Ubuntu-T430.out: No such file or directory
localhost: head: cannot open `/var/log/hadoop/anson/hadoop-anson-secondarynamenode-anson-Ubuntu-T430.out' for reading: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory `/var/log/hadoop/anson': Permission denied
chown: cannot access `/var/log/hadoop/anson': No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory `/var/run/hadoop': Permission denied
starting jobtracker, logging to /var/log/hadoop/anson/hadoop-anson-jobtracker-anson-Ubuntu-T430.out
/usr/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 136: /var/run/hadoop/hadoop-anson-jobtracker.pid: No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 135: /var/log/hadoop/anson/hadoop-anson-jobtracker-anson-Ubuntu-T430.out: No such file or directory
head: cannot open `/var/log/hadoop/anson/hadoop-anson-jobtracker-anson-Ubuntu-T430.out' for reading: No such file or directory
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory `/var/log/hadoop/anson': Permission denied
localhost: chown: cannot access `/var/log/hadoop/anson': No such file or directory
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory `/var/run/hadoop': Permission denied
localhost: starting tasktracker, logging to /var/log/hadoop/anson/hadoop-anson-tasktracker-anson-Ubuntu-T430.out
localhost: /usr/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 136: /var/run/hadoop/hadoop-anson-tasktracker.pid: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 135: /var/log/hadoop/anson/hadoop-anson-tasktracker-anson-Ubuntu-T430.out: No such file or directory
localhost: head: cannot open `/var/log/hadoop/anson/hadoop-anson-tasktracker-anson-Ubuntu-T430.out' for reading: No such file or directory
anson@anson-Ubuntu-T430:~$ cd /var/run/hadoop
-bash: cd: /var/run/hadoop: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you installed the Hadoop Debian package, and you're trying to run `start-all.sh` as a non-root user.

Here are some ideas:

1. Try following the "Standalone Operation" instructions, that should work as written.
2. Try following the "Pseudo-Distributed Operation" section as written **with one exception**: `sudo start-all.sh` instead of `bin/start-all.sh`.
3. Try completely uninstalling the Debian package and use a Hadoop release tarball instead.

If you go with the tarball option, first purge the Debian package:

```
sudo apt-get purge hadoop
```

Make sure you don't have any Hadoop-specific environment variables set. This should return nothing:

```
set | grep HADOOP
```

If you get any output from that command, reboot or manually `unset` any environment variables containing `HADOOP`.

At this point you should be able to explode the tarball and follow the "Pseudo-Distributed Operation" guide as written (and as a non-root user).

There are two tarballs. `hadoop-1.0.4.tar.gz` includes source and docs, `hadoop-1.0.4-bin.tar.gz` does not. Either works.

Answer (score 0):

The user you used for start hadoop have no permission on `/var/log`. Check the user's permissions on `/var/log/`.

Another way, you can change the hadoop base dir across  `hadoop.tmp.dir` configuration.

Comment: Which file contains the configuration of `hadoop.tmp.dir`?

Answer (score 0):

change the owner of the directory and also permissions to 755